# Weird behavior on Reciclerview inside a Dialogfragment when keyboard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I have this behavior in the ViewHolder of a recyclerview when the keyboard appears.

**on load**

[image: on load]

**keyboard**

[image: keyboard]

**scrolldown**

[image: scrolldown]

In all configurations happends the weird behaviour but this
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING
When I put this the viewHolder keeps the view but I can't write in the textbok of the button because it's under the keyboard.

**keyboard**

[image: keyboard]

I'll try to put the code, now is giving me an error of indent

Comment: Would you mind posting your layout.